# How do I call a LightBox on a click action?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please bear with me but I was giving some code to launch a lighbox. I need to display a lightbox when a user clicks on my link. The lightbox coded is in place already and is launched using a unique id. My example below uses (1111)

```
<script src="bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
lightbox = new fusepump.lightbox.buynow(1111);
var callToActionElement = document.getElementById( "unique-btn"); 
 callToActionElement.addEventListener("click", function()
{ lightbox.show(); //Show the lightbox } ); 
</script>
```

My link code is:

```
<a href="#" id="unique-btn">Buy</a>
```

For some reason it's not working.  I think that the syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: you commented out the last part of your code `//Show the lightbox } );`
The brackets never get closed and the semicolon won't be at the end of your code but in the comment. Make the comment like this `/*Show the lightbox*/`

You can also set an onClick attribute in which you can call the function name of your javascript function. It will look like this:
    `<a href="#" onclick="functionName()" id="unique-btn">Buy</a>`